# Uncaught Error: Service database is not available (Firebase and Skypack)

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, skypack-cdn

I'm trying to initialiaze Firebase and get the database reference using Skypack:

```js
import { initializeApp } from 'https://cdn.skypack.dev/@firebase/app'
import { getDatabase, onValue, push, ref, runTransaction } from 'https://cdn.skypack.dev/@firebase/database'

const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "AIzaSyBd89DtdK1HdkooqZyGAO-Tjdy9OFUGlKI",
  authDomain: "qtal-pre.firebaseapp.com",
  projectId: "qtal-pre",
  storageBucket: "qtal-pre.appspot.com",
  messagingSenderId: "542608573279",
  appId: "1:542608573279:web:860d687a1a26fd6a7decea"
}

const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig)
const db = getDatabase(app)
```

I get the following error:

> Uncaught Error: Service database is not available

When I debug both `initializeApp` and `getDatabase`, they seem to be imported correctly. I'm not quite sure if the problem is due to Skypack imports, Firebase library itself, or perhaps CodePen. Any ideas?

[Example](https://codepen.io/erikmartinjordan/pen/NWXqdXv) at CodePen.

Comment: I've found a related issue on GitHub. See [this thread](https://github.com/denoland/deploy_feedback/issues/131#issuecomment-1007323130). It solves the issue if you import from gstatic.com rather than from skypack.dev

Answer (score 0):

You're using difference versions of the Firebase SDKs. I'd update the database import to version

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).